# Changing d3 bullet chart range

Tags: jquery, d3.js

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061961

I'd like to change the x-axis range of this chart. I've been reading through the source code posted on the page but gosh, I can't find where I can control the x-axis ranges or plugin option to do that.  To make it between 20 to 80, what should I change?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In `bullet.js`, there is a `bulletRanges()` function, where you can change the ranges manually. In the example, it is changed in the `randomize()` function:

```
function randomize(d) {
  if (!d.randomizer) d.randomizer = randomizer(d);
  d.ranges = d.ranges.map(d.randomizer);  //This changes the ranges in the SVG datum.
  d.markers = d.markers.map(d.randomizer);
  d.measures = d.measures.map(d.randomizer);
  return d;
}
```

To update the chart with the data, `svg.call(chart)` is then invoked.

Comment: I don't think it does.  Ranges only changes the ranges for the shaded areas... it doesn't actually touch the X-Axis range... which (densely) remains at 0 no matter what you do.

Comment: The answer was correct in 2015! That is 3 years ago! The block was updated since then (and bullets.js).